# Is the SerializedName annotation necessary if the local field name is to be the same as the incoming data's field name?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm adapting some code I found online to my purposes. It was getting data with colum names such as "william_henry_harrison" but using locally names such as "Tippecanoe":

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("william_henry_harrison")
    public String Tippecanoe;
    @SerializedName("john_tyler")
    public String TraitorToHisCountry;
. . .
```

But in my case, I have no need for different column/field names. Right now my code is this:

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("Tippecanoe")
    public String Tippecanoe;
    @SerializedName("TylerToo") // for my great nephew Tyler ("Tyger")
    public String TylerToo;
. . .
```

...but are the @SerializedName() annotations in the latter case redundant/unnecessary where the names remain the same (to unprotect the uninnocent)? IOW, is gson smart enough to match the incoming "Tippecanoe" with the "Tippecanoe" string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need to provide the annotation if the variable name matches the input name. There are instances where you may want to name a variable something other than the input, and that is where you will need the annotation to help gson with the mapping.